Expected number of die rolls to see 2 rolls that differ by 1

On average, how many times must a 6-sided die be rolled until there are two rolls in a row that differ by 1 (such as a 2 followed by a 1 or 3, or a 6 followed by a 5)? What if we roll until there are two rolls in a row that differ by no more than 1 (so we stop at a repeated roll, too)?

Since each event (conditioned on the first throw) follows a geometric distribution, I believe the first part of the question can be solved as follows:
Let E[N] be the expected number of rolls.
E[N] = 1 + E[N|1 was rolled] * P(1 was rolled) + ... + E[N|6 was rolled] * P(6 was rolled)
(Added the 1 in the beginning to account for the first throw)
To satisfy the condition, 1 must be followed by a 2, it follows Geom(1/6). Similarly, 6 must be followed by a 5, therefore, it also follows Geom(1/6). The numbers 2,3,4, and 5 follow Geom(2/6).
For Geom(1/p), the Expected value is 1/(1/p). Hence, the following:
E[N] = 1 + 6 * 1/6 + 3 * 1/6 + 3 * 1/6 + 3 * 1/6 + 3 * 1/6 + 6 * 1/6
E[N] = 1 + 1 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 1
Therefore, E[N] = 5. But this is wrong.
The answer is 239/51. Where am I going wrong?

If you first roll a 1, and then you fail to roll a 2 on the next roll, more likely than not you've rolled a 3, 4 or 5 instead. Then you have 2/6 probability to succeed on the third roll. So rolling a 1 on the first roll doesn't lock you in to a Geom(1/6) distribution. The geometric distribution is unlikely to be useful here; instead you should consider modelling the process as a Markov chain.

Could you suggest a solution with the Markov chain process? I am not very well-versed with that concept yet. :( Thank you!

Apart from the start and stop states, you could simplify the Markov process by saying  there are effectively three other states: ${1,6}, {2,5}, {3,4}$

Consider a Markov chain with states $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ where $X_n=i$ if the $n$-th toss is $i\in\{1,\dots,6\}$ and is different from the previous toss, and $X_n=7$ if the $n$-th toss coincides with the previous one; it is the absorbing state. Hence, if $X_n=i$ then
(a) if $2\le i\le 5$, then $X_{n+1}=j$ with probability $\frac16$ for each $j\in\{1,\dots,6\}\setminus\{i-1,i+1\}$ and $X_{n+1}=0$ with probability $\frac13$;
(a) if $i=1$ or $i=6$, then $X_{n+1}=j$ with probability $\frac16$ for each $j\in\{1,\dots,6\}\setminus\{1\}$  ($\setminus\{6\}$ resp.) and $X_{n+1}=0$ with probability $\frac16$. Hence the transition probability matrix is
$$
P=\left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\frac{1}{6} & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} 
\\
 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{3} 
\\
 \frac{1}{6} & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{3} 
\\
 \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{3} 
\\
 \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} 
\\
 \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{array}\right].
$$
If $P_0$ denotes the top $6\times 6$ submatrix of $P$, and $M=(I-P_0)^{-1}$ where $I$ is the $6\times 6$ identity matrix, then the required expected time starting with $X_0=i$, $i=1,\dots,6$ is given by the coordinates of the vector $M [1,1,1,1,1,1]^T=\frac1{17}[70,58,60,60,58,70]$.
However, since in the first trial you cannot get the same number as before, so the answer should be $1+$the average of the 6 numbers above (as you are equally likely to get any number on the first roll), i.e. $1+\frac16\times\frac1{17}(70+58+60+60+58+70)=\frac{239}{51}=4.686...$
Note: you can get by with a simpler state space, where you do not distinguish $1,6$, $2,5$  and $3,4$ respectively, by symmetry. Then $S$ will have only $4$ states and $P_0$ is $3\times 3$ matrix which is easier to invert.
